# lua - Access table item from within the table

Tags: lua

I'm trying to create an object oriented implementation in Lua, for example:

```lua
Parent = {
  ChildVariable = "Hello",
  ChildFunction = function ()
     print(Parent.ChildVariable)
  end  
}
```

What I would like is rather than doing `Parent.ChildVariable` I can do `ChildVariable` instead; it is in the table so I thought must be some way to access it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Parent = {
  ChildVariable = "Hello",
  ChildFunction = function(self)
     print(self.ChildVariable)
  end  
}

Parent:ChildFunction()
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd read about this but didn't understand but this example helped!

Answer (score 4):

Lua has a special construct for that: the colon operator.
The two following lines are equivalent:

```
tbl.func(tbl)
```

and

```
tbl:func()
```